# Get an attribute from an ajax in a variable

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to get the response.responseJSON on my variable outside of my ajax

Some help please...

static getRdvBySirenAndCommercialAndDateAndBranch(siren, commercial, date, branch){

```
    let $result = $.ajax({
        url: `/services/siren/match?siren=${siren}&commercial=${commercial}&date=${date}&branch=${branch}`,
        method: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        timeout: 0,
        complete: function (response) {

            let records = response.responseJSON

            return records;
        }
    });

    return $result.response.responseJSON

}
```

}